# Finding ID FileUpload in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload, master-pages

I have several aspx pages and one site.master. I defined *.js file with any javascript functions.
And now I want to find ID of FileUpload control on one of this subpage.

```
function CheckFile()
{

var filePath = document.getElementById('<%= this.fileUp.ClientID %>').value;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use server-side code in ASPX pages, not standalone `.js` files

Instead, you should pass the control's ID from inline Javascript in your ASPX.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it problem define *.js file and link it in site.master and then use in other subpages?

Comment: @Saint: `.js` files cannot have server-side code.  When the browser sends its request for your `.js` file, your controls do not exist.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, now it works :) But I saw in some project all js function in one file. So how there must be some solution. Do you know sth about this?

Answer (score 0):

try replace $ with _ in the id.

```
var filePath = document.getElementById('<%= this.fileUp.ClientID.ToString().Replace("$","_") %>').value;
```

Comment: the `ToString()` because I'm not sure if clientId is a String

Comment: This is not true.  `ClientID` is a real ID.